# Weird Socket.IO behavior: events "on connection" and "on disconnect" happen almost at the same type

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

On the socket io server I have something like:

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(client) {
    console.log(client.id + ' connected at '+(new Date()).getTime());
    client.on('disconnect',function() {
        console.log(client.id + ' DISCONNECTED at '+(new Date()).getTime());
    });
});
```

And my problem is that this happens:

```
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 15229479751557595508
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/15229479751557595508
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 15229479751557595508
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
15229479751557595508 connected at 1313769716321
   debug - websocket received data packet 5:::{"name":"estimatepp","args":[9]}
   debug - websocket received data packet 5:::{"name":"ready","args":[null]}
   info  - transport end
   debug - set close timeout for client 15229479751557595508
   debug - cleared close timeout for client 15229479751557595508
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 15229479751557595508
15229479751557595508 DISCONNECTED at 1313769716454
   debug - discarding transport
```

I don't know if this is normal but as you can see, the client `15229479751557595508` connects at `1313769716321` and disconnects at `1313769716454`, just 133 mili-seconds later (this number is always either 132 or 133). I'm not ordering the client to disconnect after something.

Any ideas on why does this happen ?

Also I have another doubt. If I listen for connection events on io.sockets.on, shouldn't I be listening for disconnect events also there ? Except there's no client there...

What is the correct way to listen for disconnections ?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** You can ignore the lines

```
debug - websocket received data packet 5:::{"name":"estimatepp","args":[9]}
debug - websocket received data packet 5:::{"name":"ready","args":[null]}
```

It's part of the project I'm working on. Maybe the thing is that it just receives those events and after that because there's no activity for a while it closes the connection ? But this is not wanted behavior is it ?

Answer (score 0):

The server-side code that you have posted is fine and should work as expected. Check for bugs in your client-side code (or post your client-side code here). If nothing there, try a different browser.

---

Regarding your `disconnect` event.

You have an `io.sockets.on("connection", function (client) { ... })` event handler where when a new connection is made, a session is created for the connection and is stored in the client variable.

You then attach event handlers (like the `disconnect` one) to this `client` object.

Now when that client disconnects, the `disconnect` event handler attached to that particular `client` object is invoked.

Moreover, as you can see in [Exposed Events — Socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events), `io.sockets.on` only exposes the `connection` event.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar thoughts as the creator of the question.

The time in ms is probably your roundtrip time to the server or the time it takes to manage connects with the client etc etc. So I wouldnt bother so much with the time factor.

I get same result when I refresh the client manually and repeatedly. between say half and one second intervals. This seems to create a scenario which otherwise only happen with poor network quality.

I can see in the logs that I get a connection, before a disconnection with the same socket.id.
client connected:  qEcxQQCivSyKJVbF85dc
client disconnected: qEcxQQCivSyKJVbF85dc

However my on.disconnect event does in this scenario NOT fire.

On disconnects I clean up my local object of connected clients and I can see that I a client left in there and when I analyze the socket.connected status it is disconnected.

So under certain circumstances the above scenario causes a disconnect event to not fire.

Probably due to timings, asynch, network quality etc.

Two ways to go.

1. Build the application according to those constraints or
2. find someone who can come up with a more solid method for listening to on.disconnect, which, as the original question eluded, does not involve being attached to a specific socket client.

It is like the event listener is overwritten when the client connects again with the same id. A more general disconnect event listener would disregard that but potentially cause other issues instead.

I am personally going with option 1. and instead creating a garbage collector of sorts that clean up my local array of clients if they are disconnected.